# Finding a constant in inequality for softmax function

Tags: inequality, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions

Let $x, y$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\textrm{softmax}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector function such that: 
$$\textrm{softmax}(x)_i = \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum^n_{j=1} e^{x_j}}.$$

What is the lowest constant $L$  such that:
$$\forall x, y: \|\textrm{softmax} (x) - \textrm{softmax}(y)\|_{\infty} \leq L \|x - y \|_1 $$?

I have tried to invert the softmax function, but I am not sure what to do with the result or even if it is a useful thing to do.

I shall be grateful for any help in this task.

**Edit:** There is the property that

$$\forall c \in \mathbb{R}: \textrm{softmax}(x + c) = \textrm{softmax}(x),$$

where $x + c = (x_1 + c, \dots, x_n + c)$.

Then we need to find such $L$ that
$$\|\textrm{softmax}(x) - \textrm{softmax}(y)\|_{\infty} \leq L
\|(x + c_x) - (y + c_y) \|_1 = L
\|x - y + c\|_1$$
for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n, c \in \mathbb{R}$.

The right-hand side is minimal when $c = \textrm{median} \left(x_1 - y_1, \dots, x_n - y_n \right)$.

I am not sure, but maybe this can be more convenient for derivation?

Comment: For $n=1$, you have something like $||0||_\infty \le L|x-y|$ which is never true for all $x$ and $y$ right? Or is in that case $L=0$?

Comment: Running a Monte Carlo type experiment, for a few vectors of dimension $2,3,4,5$ with elements uniformly drawn from $[-a,a]$, for a few values of $a>1$ the ratio of the two seems to always be in the range
$$ 
\frac{\|\textrm{softmax} (x) - \textrm{softmax}(y)\|_{\infty}}{\|x - y \|_1 } \in[0,\frac{1}{4}] 
$$

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin for $n=1$ this will be true for any $L$, as the left-hand side is zero and right is something greater than zero, but this is degenerate case